# Identity_insert on in temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a problem running a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 and 2008 R2 while it worked fine in my SQL Server 2000 and 2005.

Please see code below:

```
SELECT * INTO #TB_Table_1
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TB_Table_2) A

TRUNCATE TABLE #TB_Table_1
```

My existing sp has this code. The purpose is only to copy the structure of `TB_Table_2`.

Note: `TB_Table_2` has an identity column `Master_ID`.

Next, I will try to insert data with the following code. And this is where I'm having trouble.

```
INSERT INTO #TB_Table_1
SELECT * FROM TB_Table_2
WHERE ISNULL(Date,'') = ''
AND ISNULL(ID,'') = ''
```

Is there something I need to set up in SQL Server to make this work?

EDIT:

the error that I am getting is

> An explicit value for the identity column in table
>   '#TB_Table_1' can only be specified when a column list is
>   used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Comment: SET IDENTITY_INSERT #TB_Master_Organization ON ?

Comment: I have tried that also but still no luck.

Comment: What error are you getting? You say it doesn't work - what is it doing?

Comment: Maybe it wants a column list now as in http://dbaspot.com/sqlserver-programming/188727-identity_insert-temp-table.html

Comment: What I do not understand though is why you need to create the table first, truncate it and then insert again. Why not lose the first SELECT INTO and just use a single one.

Comment: @anttix that's just an example. the query is more complex than that.

Comment: @zerey did you find a solution at the end?

Answer (score 5):

If your Temp Table has an Identity, to make this insert you need to first:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT #TB_Master_Organization ON
```

before the insert statement.

You will need to specify the columns to insert:

```
INSERT INTO #TB_Master_Organization (col1, col2, col3..)
SELECT * FROM TB_Master_Organization
WHERE ISNULL(DeactivatedDate,'') = ''
AND ISNULL(DeactivatedByID,'') = ''
```

and then, set off the identity_Insert.

So, you got:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT #TB_Master_Organization ON
INSERT INTO #TB_Master_Organization (col1, col2, col3..)
    SELECT * FROM TB_Master_Organization
    WHERE ISNULL(DeactivatedDate,'') = ''
    AND ISNULL(DeactivatedByID,'') = ''
SET IDENTITY_INSERT #TB_Master_Organization OFF
```

Also, if this not work, [take a look at this, maybe can help you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933208)

Comment: I have 2 temp tables that was created from the same physical table and I set IDENTITY_INSERT for both table to ON, the first temp table did not get error but the next temp table got error and telling that IDENTITY_INSERT IS ALREADY ON and IT POINTS TO THE FIRST TEMP TABLE. This is a bug right?

Answer (score 1):

Here first of all the code you have used to copy the table structure is not correct.As it copies top 1 row also into your new temp table.

To just copy the table structure you can use this below code:

```
select * INTO #TB_Master_Organization FROM TB_Master_Organization where 1=2
```

Then you can insert data explicitly by setting the IDENTITY INSERT ON on this temp table.

But You can easily achive this by just by writing this below query:

```
select * INTO #TB_Master_Organization FROM TB_Master_Organization where WHERE ISNULL(DeactivatedDate,'') = ''
AND ISNULL(DeactivatedByID,'') = ''
```

Here in one query you will get the final data in your temp table.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and I have given `isnull` conversion in the identity column of the table and the issue is fixed `ISNULL(P.PersonId,0)`.

Answer (score -1):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT #TB_Master_Organization ON

SELECT COL1,COL2 INTO #TB_Table_1 FROM TB_Table_2
```

You need to select your all columns which you want to insert into a new table and simply run.

It's work for me.